# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't restart/reboot, after installation on a new laptop

Tags: 20.04, lenovo

After installation Ubuntu 20.04 on my new laptop Lenovo-Legion-5P, I can't reboot/restart the system. I'm getting in a black screen.
CPU: intel core i7-10875H CPU 2.30GHz
GPU: nvidia GeForce RTX 2060
Bios Version: EFCN38WW

Tried this:
Boot Mode: Legasy Support --> UEFI
PTT: Enable --> Disable
This way doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I accidentally sent a message and post got deleted. To answer your question, unfortunately I can't help you manually repairing your bootloader, certainly someone here can guide you through the process. For a quick easy fix though I suggest you use the GUI tools included in [these](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/) live rescue distros, [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) is also a very good one you may want to try. Just download the image from a working machine, burn it (cd/dvd/usb) set it as first boot device in BIOS, attempt grub repair

Comment: Thank you. The problem was in drivers of GPU Nvidia.

Comment: Perfect, glad you were able to solve it